# Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 seems stuck at "Preconfiguring packages...." stage of installation

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

I'm trying to do an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, and getting stuck at the `Installing the upgrades` phase, in `Preconfiguring package....`  The terminal reports the following:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97, <> line 1621.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103, <> line 1621.
Extract templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
```

It's been stuck here for over 16 hours!  Any suggestions?  I have at least 15GB free space so that is not the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. But when I just about to abort the process, I saw a dialogue asking me to configure MySql's password. This dialogue was hidden and only showed up when I switched around with different application windows.